# keep for loop from executing in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently for loop gets executed till the end even though the function it calls hasn't finished executing. I want to make it such that, when startloop function is called until it is executed completely for loop shouldn't move forward.. How to do that? I tried simulating goto but it didn't work..

Here's my code:

```
function startLoop(i) {
  console.log("startloop function start");
  var centerX = xObj[i];
  var centerY = yObj[i];
  var radius = 10;

  var alpha = 1, /// current alpha value
    delta = 0.01; /// delta = speed
  var flag = 0;
  var num = 0

  function loop() {
    console.log("inside loop " + centerX + " " + centerY);
    alpha -= delta;
    if (alpha <= 0) {
      //console.log("heya_amigoes");
      num = 2;
      return;
    }
    //console.log("hi1");
    /// clear canvas, set alpha and re-draw image
    ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 600);
    ctx2.globalAlpha = alpha;
    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx2.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx2.fill();
    ctx2.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx2.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    ctx2.stroke();

    //console.log("hi2");
    //requestAnimationFrame(loop); // or use setTimeout(loop, 16) in older browsers
    setTimeout(loop, 16)
    console.log("Outside function loop");
  }

  loop();

  /*  
     LABEL1: do {
          if(num==2)
              {
              num=0;
              break LABEL1;
              }
          if(num!=2)
              continue LABEL1;
      }while(1);
  */

  console.log("startloop function stop");
}

for (i = 0; i < xObj.length; i++) {
  console.log("for loop running " + i);
  startLoop(i);
  console.log("outside loop func");
}
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and the rest of the html to show a [mcve] - it is currently not clear at all what your expected and actual output is

Comment: You will have to use recursion and function callbacks for it

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai - making a snippet means making working code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop will not wait for your task. To achieve this task, you will have to use `recursion`.

**Logic:**

- Call a function and pass a callback in it.
- On execution completion, run passed callback.
- Now since we have to chain same function again and again, pass same callback to next iteration again and have a check(*threshold limit*) and stop on breach.

```js
var count = 0

function test1(i, cb){
  console.log("In Test " + i)
  if(i < 10)
    setTimeout(cb.bind(null, ++count, cb), 2000)
}


test1(count, test1)
```

---

**Explanation:**

My approach mimics behaviour of a `do..while` loop. It has 4 parts:

1. **Initialisation**: This will initialise the iterator variable. This variable will be use to check for termination condition and to check the current iterator's value. In my Case: `count = 0`
2. **Execution of Code block**: This will execute the code defined inside `{...}`. In my case: `test1(count, test1)`
3. **Termination condition**: This check if next iteration should be performed or not? In my case: `if(i<10)`. If condition is satisfied, start next iteration: `setTimeout(cb.bind(null, ++count, cb), 2000)`
4. **Increment Value**: This updated value of iterator to point to next value. In my case: `++count`

---

This is the final [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1o3e8sbs/4/)

Comment: Hey can you plz explain how your code snippet is working plz? what does the initLoop do? and how can i use this in my code?

Comment: ok I am trying to do that.. and the function test1 gets replaced by my second function loop?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1o3e8sbs/
Hey check this fiddle out. I tried using your code with a for loop just to check if it works but it is giving unexpected results..

Comment: Also i think, instead of using for loop, i can set the length to a variable say `x` and using your code i can check that, `if(i<x)` maybe? and pass the value of next i to get the desired co-ordinates?

Comment: Please check the update. Have added explanation and made code snippet little more simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem going to be with your `for` loop. `startLoop` function always going to get the `xObj.length-1`.

You can read more about this problem: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

> The variable `i`, within each of your anonymous functions, is bound to
>   the same variable outside of the function.

Solution with ES6 `let` feature:

```
for (let i = 0; i < xObj.length; i++) {
  console.log("for loop running " + i);

  startLoop(i);

  console.log("outside loop func");

}
```

Solution without ES6:

```
var funcs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < xObj.length; i++) {
  funcs[i] = startLoop(i);
}

for (var i = 0; i < xObj.length; i++) {
  console.log("for loop running " + i);

  funcs[i]();

  console.log("outside loop func");

}
```

Comment: no this is not the case as i am passing the value of i and getting the values inside the function.. problem is it's not one after one. it keeps getting executed one by one with decreasing alpha value